# Link error using cocos2d

Tags: ios, c++11, xcode6, cocos2d-x

I am getting this error at link time in cocos2d-x

> Ld
>   /Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Intermediates/AlphabetsTeacher.build/Debug-iphoneos/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/hareesh/Desktop/AlphabetsTeacher/proj.ios_mac
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode
>   6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode\ 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/hareesh/Desktop/AlphabetsTeacher/Resources -F/Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Intermediates/AlphabetsTeacher.build/Debug-iphoneos/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -liconv -lcurl -framework Security /Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d\
>   iOS.a -framework CoreMotion -framework Foundation -framework UIKit
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -lz -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Intermediates/AlphabetsTeacher.build/Debug-iphoneos/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/hareesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlphabetsTeacher-bkssouxddsguabddecsiknanrlci/Build/Intermediates/AlphabetsTeacher.build/Debug-iphoneos/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AlphabetsTeacher-mobile
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/hareesh/Desktop/AlphabetsTeacher/Resources/libcurl.a, missing
>   required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/hareesh/Desktop/AlphabetsTeacher/Resources/libcurl.a (3 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "vtable for
>   Alphabet_MenuLayer", referenced from:
>         Alphabet_MenuLayer::Alphabet_MenuLayer() in Alphabet_MenuScene.o   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual
>   member function has no definition. ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: once check by changing bundle identifier

Comment: That's during linking, not running.  You are missing libraries...